# images are not getting served from angular build dist in another project

Tags: angular, angular-builder

In angular i have created a project that shows a widget in which I am using images.

If i run this project, images are getting served.

Now I have created the build out of this project and I want to use in my other react project,

so i have imported all the js files from dist in one of the react project, and widget get loaded but without images..

```
import "<private-repo>/dist/runtime.js";
```

in dist folder there is assets folder.

and and the build project this is how i am using images

```
<img  src="../assets/images/icons/my-image.png">
```

but there is no such images browser sources.

If i import the image in react project from the `dist/assets` the image gets loaded in browser but not visible on ui (due to i guess image path)

Any help?